# Deploying to Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I opened up a unity project and simply put a cube on the scene view. I then got it to deploy in Visual Studio 2019 without any errors.

When I viewed it in Hololens 2, it shows up as a blank image with no error message to be found anywhere.

Any idea as to what could be happening that would cause this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you once look at it through the GameView in Unity? Is your camera maybe **IN** that cube so it is backface culled?

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't add a comment yet, here's an answer that should be seen as an addition to Hernando - MSFT's answer.
Additionally to the scaling of the cube, it makes sense to position it reasonably. As already mentioned, one unit corresponds to one meter.
In the Inspectorview of the cube, Z is the distance to the camera and X and Y are the horizontal and vertical offsets.

Reasonable values for the mentioned position are `X/Y/Z` equal to `0/0/0.5` for example. Then the cube should be in front of you after starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you manipulated the cube's `Scale` property after adding the cube into your scene?

In MR spatial coordinate system, 1 unit = 1 meter, and the default `Scale` property of the new cube is "1, 1, 1". This means that the cube will be too large to completely block your view, so you can only see a blank.

We recommend that you try to manipulate the cube's `Scale` property to "0.1, 0.1, 0.1" for testing, if you see any different behavior, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be

- your box is too large and near the camera
- or the Clear Flags of Camera is Skybox. If so, you can try to use DefaultHololens2ConfiurationProfile